# When and why were answer acceptance percentages removed?

Tags: support, profile-page, accept-rate

I just noticed on Stack Overflow that the acceptance percentage is missing on questions and peoples' profiles? Why was this removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only users who have asked at least 4 non-wiki questions that are open, older than 3 days, and have at least one answers have their Accept Rate displayed.

Answer (score 4):

That's explained here

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

> The following rules are used in the calculation:
>
> - Questions must not be community wiki.
> - Questions must not be closed.
> - Questions must be more than 3 days old.
> - Questions must have at least 1 answer.
> - There must be at least four eligible questions as determined by the above rules, otherwise the statistic will not appear.

Comment: This information has been copied to a FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235, near "What's with the Accept Rate?"

Answer (score 3):

They were never there. They show up in questions only.

See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009718/something-wrong-with-redirects-on-my-joomla-1-5-18-site)

I can see your 92% percentage.

Comment: some peoples questions don't show their percentages

Comment: @fuzzy see Waiwai's answer for that.